# how to bind a command from DataContext of Page to a list item

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have a Page and a viewmodel is set as its datacontext. in that page I have a list. which is populating through a property in the viewmodel. List has a user control. and that user control has a button. I want that button to be bind with a command that is in viewmodel. Is there anyway to do that?

```
<Page DataContext=PageViewModel>
...
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="3" Margin="20,0" Visibility="{Binding ByVenueSelected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding EventsListByVenue}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <myControls:EventDetails /> <!--in this control i want to bind a command available in PageViewModel-->
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
...
</Page>
```

Comment: Take my answer back, if you are using MVVMlight with a static resource locator, perharps you can try DataContext="{Binding MainPageViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" otherwise i'll need to look this up when i get on a computer that has wp dev setup later.

Comment: @FunksMaName using it this way worked me except the command parameter is being null. <Button Style="{StaticResource NoHighlightButtonStyle}" Visibility="{Binding link,Converter={StaticResource DataAvailabilityToVisibilityConverter}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Link}" Command="{Binding Path=Event.LinkCommand,Source={StaticResource Locator}}" >
                <TextBlock Margin="0,5" Foreground="SkyBlue" Text="{Binding link}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16"/>
            </Button>

Comment: Do you want to create a button on the run? Dynamic?

Comment: @max no but yet its some sort of, being in an List/ItemsControl it will be populated on runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with help of @FunksMaName, I solved this. I am sure there are more elegant and better approach, but yet this is a quick & easy solution for me:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource NoHighlightButtonStyle}" Tag="{Binding link}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Tag,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Visibility="{Binding link,Converter={StaticResource DataAvailabilityToVisibilityConverter}}" Command="{Binding Path=Event.LinkCommand,Source={StaticResource Locator}}" >
                <TextBlock Margin="0,5" Foreground="SkyBlue" Text="{Binding link}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16"/>
</Button>
```

things to note:
i think xaml searched the command parameter in context of command only, so it was giving me null parameter, while the same binding was working fine for textblock inside Button. So i tricked it to store the value in tag, and used it from there.

```
Tag="{Binding link}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Tag,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
```